# Using 4 monitors with 2 generic video cards... possible?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, pci, pci-express

I'm thinking of setting up 4 monitors in a grid, using two video cards, one card to feed each pair of monitors through the card's two DVI ports. The most important requirement for me is to have the grid of monitors act as one single huge screen.

Is this scenario possible by using two generic cards like Radeon 4870s on a Windows 7 computer? (I've heard of Eyefinity, but 4870s don't have it)

Another issue is that I only have one PCI-Express slot on my computer's motherboard, therefore I'll need to use one of the lesser PCI cards as the second video card. Will this pose problems?

Comment: What's your application? Is this gaming? Professional imaging? Or what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It is for normal office use, though I just realized browsing the web with such a setup will be unusable, with the space between the monitors running down the middle of the sites I view.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. We run a exotic mix of integrated graphics and an additional video card at work with four monitors without any (major) issues.
I would advice to use videocards from the same manufacturer to avoid having the mess with multiple video drivers.